# How to handle http GET request in an app with bottom navigation

Tags: http, dart, flutter

I'm currently working on an app that has multiple pages and using bottom navigation bar, every page needs to send an HTTP GET request to a different API endpoint.

Right now I call the get function inside the initState() of every page. As a result, every time I tap on the navigation bar to go to the corresponding page, it will send another HTTP GET request all over again. How can I handle this? should I send the GET request from the Bottom Navigation page?

I've tried using the PageStorageKey method but I think the problem is that I called the GET method inside the initState of every page.

MyTab.dart

```
bottomNavigationBar: Theme(
    data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
          // sets the background color of the `BottomNavigationBar`
          canvasColor: Color(0xff3a3637),
          // sets the active color of the `BottomNavigationBar` if `Brightness` is light
          primaryColor: Color(0xffffd51e),
          textTheme: Theme.of(context).textTheme.copyWith(
                caption: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              ),
        ), // sets the inactive color of the `BottomNavigationBar`

    child: BottomNavigationBar(
      type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
      currentIndex: currentTab,
      onTap: (int index) {
        setState(() {
          currentTab = index;
          currentPage = pages[index];
        });
      },

      items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[

        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: ImageIcon(AssetImage("assets/icon/anggota_white.png")),
          title: Text(
            'Anggota',
            style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'MyriadPro'),
          ),
        ),

        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: ImageIcon(AssetImage("assets/icon/bk_white.png")),
          title: Text(
            "BK",
            style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'MyriadPro'),
          ),
        ),

        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: ImageIcon(AssetImage("assets/icon/himatif_white.png")),
          title: Text(
            "Himatif",
            style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'MyriadPro'),
          ),
        ),

        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.search),
          title: Text(
            "Cari",
            style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'MyriadPro'),
          ),
        ),

        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: ImageIcon(AssetImage("assets/icon/kkm_white.png")),
          title: Text(
            "KKM",
            style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'MyriadPro'),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
```

Here is one the the page,

AnggotaScreen.dart

```
class AnggotaScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  AnggotaScreen({
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _AnggotaScreenState createState() => _AnggotaScreenState();
}

class _AnggotaScreenState extends State<AnggotaScreen> {
  bool _isLoading;
  var _dataAngkatan, _dataTahun;
  static String _uriAngkatan;

  _ambilData(String url, bool tipe) async {
    final response = await http.get(url);

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final map = json.decode(response.body);

      if (tipe == true) {
        setState(() {
          _dataAngkatan = map;
          _isLoading = false;
        });
      } else {
        setState(() {
          _dataTahun = map;
          _isLoading = false;
        });
      }
    }
  }

  // initState
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _isLoading = true;
    _uriAngkatan = "2012";
    _dataAngkatan = [];
    _dataTahun = [];
    _ambilData(Url.TAHUN_ANGGOTA, false);
    _ambilData(Url.angkatan(_uriAngkatan), true);
  }
  ..........
}
```

I'd like to make the page send the GET request only once on the start and hold that state until the app closed, but right now it will send the GET request every time I open that page.

Answer (score 2):

`Offstage` A widget that lays the child out as if it was in the tree, but without painting anything, without making the child available for hit testing, and without taking any room in the parent. 
 `TickerMode` which can be used to disable animations in a subtree

https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Offstage-class.html

```
body: Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                new Offstage(
                  offstage: index != 0,
                  child: new TickerMode(
                      enabled: index == 0,
                      child: Screen() //MainScreen(),
                      ),
                ),
                new Offstage(
                  offstage: index != 1,
                  child: new TickerMode(
                    enabled: index == 1,
                    child: Screen(),
                  ),
                ),
                new Offstage(
                  offstage: index != 2,
                  child: new TickerMode(
                    enabled: index == 2,
                    child: Screen(),
                  ),
                ),
                new Offstage(
                  offstage: index != 3,
                  child: new TickerMode(
                    enabled: index == 3,
                    child: Screen(),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            )
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are right. I have developed a similar app with similar situation, and I sent all the http request at initState of the parent page (Bottom Navigation page in your case) to avoid sending multiple http requests. Just send the request and hold the data at the parent page and pass those data down to each children pages.